# Help identifying a possible connector for these unterminated contacts on my HP Stream 14 motherbard

Tags: connector, identification, pcie, motherboard, sata

I'm trying to identify the appropriate connector for this bundle of unterminated contacts, from my HP Stream 14 motherboard.

I'm talking about the red circled part of the motherboard:
[image]

Here's a close up:
[image]

The number of contacts are:

\$4 \qquad\qquad 29\$

\$5 \qquad\qquad 29\$

The first picture, with unsoldered contacts, was pulled from the internet. The second picture is of my actual motherboard.

---

The reason for asking is that the Intel Celeron embedded on this motherboard (https://ark.intel.com/products/91832/Intel-Celeron-Processor-N3060-2M-Cache-up-to-2_48-GHz) supposedly has

```
4 PCIe lanes
1 DisplayPort/HDMI (integrated graphics in CPU)
5 USB ports (some 2.0, some 3.0)
2 SATA
1 UART
1 GPIO.
```

\$\$

```
The screen uses the DisplayPort/eDP.
The physical HDMI port is most likely in dual-mode with the DisplayPort above.
There are physically 2 USB 3.0 and 1 USB 2.0 ports
The keyboard might take up either a USB or the UART or the GPIO.
The trackpad might also take up  a USB or the UART or the GPIO.
The M.2 slot uses 2 of the PCIe lane.
```

---

So really, there are more or less:

```
2 PCIe lanes made unavailable
0 to 2 USB ports (some 2.0, some 3.0) made unavailable
2 SATA made unavailable
0 to 1 UART made unavailable 
0 to 1 GPIO made unavailable
```

So perhaps some of the unavailable lanes above are on the unterminated contacts?

How do I test?

But really, the easier way of going about this is identifying the connector.

Comment: Looks like mini PCIe.

Comment: What does empotted mean?

Answer (score 5):

That looks like a footprint for an [M.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M.2) connector (though not the exact one in the picture below). Specifically, it looks like an "M key" connector, so it could be connected to a PCIe interface and/or a SATA interface. They are often used for things like SSDs and Wi-Fi cards.

[image: M.2 connector]